# Unable to use swagger 3.0.1 in Azure logic apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, azure-logic-apps

When I try to add a swagger endpoint from my logic app it fails even though it successfully fetches the content.

> Failed to fetch swagger with error message: Invalid response: {"openapi":"3.0.1","info":{"title":"My Swagger API" 
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...} Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint and are calling a valid HTTPS endpoint.

I tried trouble-shooting CORS in every possible way, but in the end what got it working was forcing version 2.0 of swagger:
`app.UseSwagger(o => o.SerializeAsV2 = true);`

Has anyone gotten swagger 3.x to work with Logic Apps?

Comment: How is the CORS set on the API?

Comment: @theabodeofcode right now I have set allow origin "*" in the swagger app service (azure portal).

Comment: That should be sufficient enough, do you have any custom urls in the allow origin?

Comment: @theabodeofcode none, but as I stated above: it works with swagger 2.0, but gives me an error on swagger 3.x with everything else the same.

Comment: Okay, I will try to replicate this behavior on my end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have replicated the issue on my end and I have observed the same issue with the my open API.
The key word to notice here is "OpenAPI" specification. This is not a swagger specification. I found the official document which clearly says Swagger(not OpenAPI). Please refer [Call REST endpoints by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http-swagger)

You can try work around for this by creating custom connector

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can't believe I missed that it actually says "not OpenAPI".